# Check pressed keyboard keys from on_touch_down in kivy

Tags: keyboard, kivy, mouse

I know there are methods like `on_keyboard_down` that report pressed keys. Is there a way to check a keyboard status from other methods? I want to distinguish modifier key presses from inside the `on_touch_down` that is invoked by mouse to use events like "Ctrl + Left Mouse Button" etc.

Comment: I think you would have to use both methods. The keyboard methods to keep the state of the modifier keys, and `on_touch_down` would then check that modifier state.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I do now. I just thought there might be a way to access keyboard state from everywhere